# Is it possible to use a wifi network adapter in a Linux (guest) in a Virtual Machine in monitor mode?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, virtualbox, vmware

Setup:
Host: Computer with Windows10 OS 64bit
Guest: Linux Ubuntu v22.04LTS 64bit
Network wifi adapter: Tenda U1 (Realtek 802.11n)

What is to be achived:
Put the Tenda into monitor mode using airmon-ng and start to capture network packets
I do not want an internet connection from Host machine to Guest machine for internet access

What I have tried:
I am using VMware (Workstation 17 Player - the free version). When I connect the Tenda into the USB port, I am being asked where to connect it - to the host or to the Virtual Machine. But in the same time another window about removable devices appears, but it is empty.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjGTl.jpg)

Even if I choose to use the adapter in the Virtual Machine, Windows (the Host) is still the only one able to manage the device. In Linux (the Guest) the adapter is only seen as a wired connection and gets internet access from the Host. iwconfig says no wireless extension.
When i connedc a USB storage stick, I am asked the same question: which system should use it - the Host or Guest. Even if I select the Guest (Linux), the stick is still opened by Windows autoplay feature. And the stick is not visible in Linux.
Both the storage stick and Tenda adapter appear gray out and unselectable in the VMware 'Removable Devices'

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToE1s.jpg)

Questions:
Does the VMware behaves that way because it is the free version?
Is it possible to use a wifi adapter in a virtual machine in monitor mode using VMware?
Maybe Windows Hyper-V? Maybe other virtualisation program?

Comment: I am using VirtualBox and such things always worked fine. When I connect an USB device to the guest it's gone from the host completely.

Answer (score 2):

I have the latest Workstation Pro and it still doesn't have a wireless
NIC type, so direct wireless hardware access is out.

For a network adapter of type USB, USB Passthrough requires Workstation Pro.

USB Passthrough means to disconnect the USB device that is connected
to your computer from the host operating system and connect it to a
VMware virtual machine, where it can be used natively by the guest.

If you're willing to pass to Workstation Pro for this option,
you will find more information about USB Passthrough in VMware
in the article:
[How to Passthrough USB Devices on VMware Workstation Pro 16 Virtual Machines](https://linuxhint.com/passthrough-usb-devices-vmware-workstation/).

Comment: I have a like setup and have USB pass through working